# Facebook JS API does not work with progressive web app

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, progressive-web-apps

- I have a "Progressive Web App" installed to my phone's homescreen.
- The [Facebook Javascript SDK](https://connect.facebook.net/en_us/sdk.js) it trying to open a login dialog popup window using `window.open`.
- This results in an about:blank tab being opened in Chrome which never loads, and never redirects the user back to the web app.

Does anyone have any advice or experience with this problem? I imagine since these "Homescreen Apps" are fairly new, this might not be a well known issue (yet).

[image: /*1480978243,,JIT Construction: v2721176,en_US*/]

Comment: I'm about to being a similar bit of work next week. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @rashadb not really... I just implemented a custom oauth redirect flow instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

Comment: @d-_-b But even the custom flow does end up opening a new window. Doesn't it ?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427462/facebook-js-sdk-progressive-web-app-issue

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this.

Comment: @Sachin no, you can just put `<a href="oauth_url_here">Login with provider</a>` and don't open the link in a new tab/window.

Comment: any solution? .. i'm also stucked .. it hopen the Fb pages.. log user..but after that ..page not close and redirect not work on PWA :-(

Comment: I've posted a solution for this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112300/facebook-login-not-working-in-pwa-app-if-app-is-in-stand-alone-state/52451531#52451531

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it [was a bug with Chrome itself](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=771418). Should be fixed by now (Chrome 68 was released the 24th of July).