# Clicking link with target _blank makes browser close new tab immediatly

Tags: html, browser, hyperlink

Clicking on a link to our webpage using

```
<a href="our.webpage.org" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

opens a new tab and closes it immediatly. This happens on all browsers apparently. Deactivating adblock and alike does not change anything.
Using the url without target="_blank" or right click -> open in new Tab however works fine.

The web page is an angular project and does not use any sort of trackers. Furthermore this behavior started only recently, so I assume it's due to some change in the page.

Any hint why this happens or where to start debugging this?

Comment: As a possible solution, could you use JavaScript instead? For example, `onclick="window.open('our.webpage.org')"`

Comment: @LucaNeri Good guess, just tried it, but the same happens: The window opens and is closed immediatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
I had a line `window.close();` due to a workaround for a popup for facebook login, implementing this:
[Facebook Login not working in PWA app if app is in stand alone state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112300/facebook-login-not-working-in-pwa-app-if-app-is-in-stand-alone-state)